# C++ Macro to use values of variables

Tags: c++, macros, turbo-c++

I have a program with 4 objects of a class, say PO1, PO2, PO3, PO4.
I want to call some functions taking these objects as parameters in a for loop. 
Like so:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
    func(PO<i>);    //Something like a macro to replace the value i in the function.
```

I tried token pasting, but all I got was POi, instead of getting the value of i. 
Is there any way to do this? (Macro, Function, etc.)

Here's my code

```
Player PO[4] = {Player{'l',WHITE},
                Player{'l',WHITE},
                Player{'l',WHITE},
                Player{'l',WHITE}
               };
```

'l' and WHITE are the parameters.

Comment: The proper way to do this is to use an array, instead of "PO1", "PO2", "PO3", and "PO4". This is what arrays (or vectors) are for.

Comment: Unfortunately, each of the objects has a non-default constructor.

Comment: As I said: use an array. You can have an array of objects with non-default constructors, you know. Or, alternatively, an array of references to the four objects. That'll work, too.

Comment: Could you give an example? I couldn't make one that way.

Comment: `po_object *po[4];`, and in the constructor's initialization section: `po{&PO1,&PO2,&PO3,&PO4}`

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Where should I put the second bit of code?

Comment: The initialization section of the constructor, of course.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Look at my answer. Is that fine? It seems to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @SamVarshavchik's comment, I got a solution.

Here it is,

```
Player *PK[4] = {&PO1,&PO2,&PO3,&PO4};
for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++}{
    func(*PK[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use array or `std::vector` instead

```
MyObject Pos[4] = {MyObject{42}, MyObject{51}, MyObject{21}, MyObject{12}};

for (auto& po : Pos) {
    func(Po);
}
```

Comment: Wait. Let me just try that. Doesn't seem to work. I'll just type in the errors I get.

Comment: 1) Initialization is only partially bracketed.
2) Improper use of typedef MyObject(The class name)

Comment: You've left out a `}` or maybe a `)` somewhere.

Comment: There's no ) anywhere. I checked

Comment: Or possibly the turboC++ tag coming into play. @user2505282 your compiler is decades old. A lot of the advice you'll get here won't work for you.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you elaborate? What's wrong in the typedef?
I'll update my code in the question.

Comment: Ask another question with a small sample of ACTUAL code that exhibits your problem.    The way you're doing it, people can only guess

Comment: @user4581301 That's probably the problem